# Share image on custom twitter share button

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter, share

I have experience on how to share feed in facebook. Recently I turn to use twitter and would like to create a custom share button in my website.

The problem is , I reference to the photo card tutorial but the image is not show,

it works when I share plain text

```
$('#twitter_share').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var loc = "<?= base_url(uri_string()); ?>";
    var title  = "<?= $video->title; ?>";

    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + title + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
});
```

but fail when I share image, and I only need share one image.

```
$('#twitter_share').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var loc = "<?= base_url(uri_string()); ?>";
    var title  = "<?= $video->title; ?>";
    var image  = "<?= isset($video->image_url) ? site_url("thumbnail/" . $video->image_url) : site_url("assets/img/cms/video.png"); ?>";

    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?card=photo&image=' + image + '&url=' + loc + '&title=' + title + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
});
```

any fix of it? Thanks for helping.

The reference link:
https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/photo

And all I need to share in the feed is:

1. current url
2. title
3. description
4. image

Comment: Are you debugging on prod or on localhost? Have you tried using metadata instead of query string? Do you comply with the requirement ?`Twitter will not create a photo card unless the twitter:image is of a minimum size of 280px wide by 150px tall. Images will not be cropped unless they have an exceptional aspect ratio. Images must be less than 1MB in size.`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can it achieve without using meta but jquery? As that can in facebook..it use the FB.UI and all I need is to provide the parameter (image url)